# How do I validate XML document using compact RELAX NG schema in Python?

Tags: python, xml, relaxng

How do I validate XML document via compact RELAX NG schema in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating with an XML schema in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299588/validating-with-an-xml-schema-in-python)

Comment: @TörökGábor that question does not ask about relax ng

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/validation.html#relaxng)?

From the docs:

```
>>> f = StringIO('''\
... <element name="a" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
...  <zeroOrMore>
...     <element name="b">
...       <text />
...     </element>
...  </zeroOrMore>
... </element>
... ''')
>>> relaxng_doc = etree.parse(f)
>>> relaxng = etree.RelaxNG(relaxng_doc)

>>> valid = StringIO('<a><b></b></a>')
>>> doc = etree.parse(valid)
>>> relaxng.validate(doc)
True

>>> invalid = StringIO('<a><c></c></a>')
>>> doc2 = etree.parse(invalid)
>>> relaxng.validate(doc2)
False
```

Comment: Thanks! Althought lxml does not support compact syntax, it's possible to convert it to xml with Trang http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html

Comment: Is there a way to get useful feedback when the document is not valid, instead of just False?

Comment: If anybody comes along and gets to this point and wonders if there is an answer to the previous question, the answer is yes.  The list of issues is kept in `relaxng.error_log` (in the context of the code above).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelTiller for `error_log` info. Anyway, I have found lxml validation of RelaxNG rather poor - it does not address the failing part of validated document properly (reporting location "xml:1:0" for all errors). It is hard to compare it to reporting provided by `jing`.

Comment: @MaximSloyko Note, that your question is asking (inside the text, not in the title) about validation using **compact** RELAX NG schema, and the answer shows only XML variant, so this is not answering your question.

Comment: From `https://lxml.de/validation.html`

      "libxml2 does not currently support the RelaxNG Compact Syntax. However, if 
      rnc2rng is installed, lxml 3.6 and later can use it internally to parse the input 
      schema. It recognises the .rnc file extension and also allows parsing an RNC 
      schema from a string using RelaxNG.from_rnc_string()."

I couldn't get this to work, though.  Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check syntax vs **Compact** RelaxNG Syntax from command line, you can use `pyjing`, from the [jingtrang](https://pypi.org/project/jingtrang/) module.

It supports **.rnc** files and displays more details than just `True` or `False`. For example:

```
C:\>pyjing -c root.rnc invalid.xml
C:\invalid.xml:9:9: error: element "name" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag or element "bounds"
```

*NOTE: it is a Python wrapper of the Java `jingtrang` so it requires to have Java installed.*

If you want to check the syntax from within Python, you can

1. Use `pytrang` (from *jingtrang* wrapper) to convert "Compact RelaxNG" (**.rnc**) to XML RelaxNG (**.rng**):
   `pytrang root.rnc root.rng`
2. Use `lxml` to parse converted **.rng** file like this: https://lxml.de/validation.html#relaxng

That would be something like that:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from subprocess import call

>>> call("pytrang root.rnc root.rng")

>>> with open("root.rng") as f:
...    relaxng_doc = etree.parse(f)
>>> relaxng = etree.RelaxNG(relaxng_doc)

>>> valid = StringIO('<a><b></b></a>')
>>> doc = etree.parse(valid)
>>> relaxng.validate(doc)
True

>>> invalid = StringIO('<a><c></c></a>')
>>> doc2 = etree.parse(invalid)
>>> relaxng.validate(doc2)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using jingtrang or other external tools is to use the Python library called [rnc2rng](https://pypi.org/project/rnc2rng/).  This can load the file in RNC format, convert it to ReleaxNG XML format as a string, which can be loaded into lxml's RelaxNG class.

See [this issue](https://github.com/djc/rnc2rng/issues/43) for details.