# python xml validation with xsd file

Tags: python, xml, validation, xsd

Every year or so someone seems to ask the same question. Is there a good Python library to validate xml files comparing them to an xsd schema? The closest I've found is suggestions involving lxml, which unfortunately is not pure python (based on a few C libraries)

Comment: Look Here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299588/validating-with-an-xml-schema-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be surprised to find any pure Python XSD validation libraries. I am aware of the following alternatives for CPython, but they all depend on non-Python code:

- [lxml](http://lxml.de) (based on libxml2)
- [libxml2 Python bindings](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html)
- [XSV](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~ht/xsv-status.html)
- [MSXML with PyWin32](http://www.burgaud.com/py-tips-msxml-val-pywin32/)

Comment: I ended up rolling with lxml. I was originally worried about creating an executable for windows from this and the library not being included. Thankfully with what I'm working with, it looks like I'm good to go

Answer (score 1):

I've used [XSV](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/XSV) for this.  It's about four years since any active dev, but it works.