# python unittest multiple mixins

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a way of testing some XML files. The XML files describe input into a scientific analysis program where various parameters can be defined. I want to write unittests for my XML files so I know that the program is configured correctly.

I'm currently doing this as a library with a base test class containing various tests and some mixins for subcomponents. But the subcomponents are repeated a number of times so I want the tests to run once for each mixin e.g.:

```
class BaseTest(object):
    xmlfile = '...'
    ...

class ComponentMixin(object):
    xmlid = None   # 
    var = None     # 

    def test_var(self):
        assert self.var == "whatever_the_value_is_in self.xmlfile"
    # ... and a number of other tests and variables.
```

... now for each analysis there can be a number of components defined with different parameters. I'm hoping to do something like this --

```
 class MyFirstComponentMixin(ComponentMixin):
      xmlid = 'component1'
      var = 'one'

 class MySecondComponentMixin(ComponentMixin):
      xmlid = 'component2'
      var = 'two'

 class MyTest(BaseTest, MyFirstComponentMixin, MySecondComponentMixin, unittest.TestCase):
      xmlfile = '...'
```

... but the problem is that test_var will only be called for component2 and not component2. Is there a way around this, or a better solution?

Comment: Prefer composition to inheritance. Why do you combine two "mixins" in one test? Why won't you create two separate tests and combine them into a [test suite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#grouping-tests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you were advised in comment: composition is better solution for your problem than inheritance. The idea is to define multiple standalone `TestCase`s (parts) for pieces of the XML file and then compose them into single `TestSuite` (composite).

**Library**

It is a base class for part.

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    xmlfile = None  # will be set by containing test suite
```

It is an abstract component test case implementation.

```
class ComponentTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    xmlid = None
    var = None

    def test_var(self):
        assert self.var == "whatever_the_value_is_in self.xmlfile"
```

It is a base for our composite. It defines convenient copying of the `xmlfile` from composite to its parts.

```
class BaseTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):
    xmlfile = None

    def addTest(self, test):
        if isinstance(test, BaseTestCase):
            test.xmlfile = self.xmlfile

        super(BaseTestSuite, self).addTest(test)
```

**Usage**

It is specific part, which tests some specific aspect of the XML:

```
class MySpecificTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def test_something_specific(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 2 + 2)
```

These are parts, which test particular components:

```
class MyFirstComponentTestCase(ComponentTestCase):
    xmlid = 'component1'
    var = 'one'


class MySecondComponentTestCase(ComponentTestCase):
    xmlid = 'component2'
    var = 'two'
```

Here is a composite with XML you want to test.

```
class MyTest(BaseTestSuite):
    xmlfile = '<some_xml></some_xml>'
```

We define [load_tests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) to return `TestSuite` with all `TestCase`s included.

```
def load_tests(loader, standard_tests, pattern):
    return MyTest((
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MySpecificTestCase),
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MyFirstComponentTestCase),
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MySecondComponentTestCase)
    ))
```

This approach has one limitation: you can't test few XML files from the single Python file. Basically you can, but output won't help you to identify, which XML file is broken.

---

Your case is a bit tricky. `unittest` were designed to test code, not data. Maybe [validation against XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299588/validating-with-an-xml-schema-in-python) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

While the title of this question was exactly what I was looking for, the answer doesn't exactly fit my case.

Perhaps because this question is about testing of data, rather than code.

Still, I found [this](https://gist.github.com/jorotenev/922a0ca6071a94f495ab0fa2c5222647) example (code copy-pasted below) of using multiple inheritances to implement multiple mixins.

Before following this pattern, though, I recommend reading up on [multiple inheritance in python is hard - by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201210/multiple_inheritance_is_hard.html), and this [Deep Dive into Python Mixins and Multiple Inheritance](https://coderbook.com/@marcus/deep-dive-into-python-mixins-and-multiple-inheritance/).

```py
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
"""
Showcase how to use mixins and multiple inheritance to write tests
"""
class BaseTest(TestCase):
    """
    A base class to be inheritated by actuall test classes.
    """
    def setUp(self):  # 3
        print("BaseTest:setUp called") 
        self.boo = "gladen sum"

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):  # 1
        print("BaseTest::setUpClass called")
        cls.browser = 'musaka'

class FullDBMixin(object):

    def setUp(self):  # 5
        super(FullDBMixin, self).setUp()
        print("FullDBMixin::setUp called with instance attribute [boo] = %s" % self.boo)

 
class LoginMixin(object):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):  # 2
        super(LoginMixin, cls).setUpClass()
        print("LoginMixin::setUpClass called")

    def setUp(self):  # 4
        super(LoginMixin, self).setUp()
        print("LoginMixin::setUp called")

        self.login()
    
    def login(self): 
        print("LoginMixin::login called with class attribute [browser] %s" % self.browser)


# order of inheritance **matters**
class TestAuthontecation(LoginMixin, FullDBMixin , BaseTest):

    def test_user_dashboard(self):
        # test stuff without needing to setup the db or login the user      
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

# georgi@georgi-laptop:~$ python test.py 
# BaseTest::setUpClass called
# LoginMixin::setUpClass called
# BaseTest:setUp called
# FullDBMixin::setUp called with instance attribute [boo] = gladen sum
# LoginMixin::setUp called
# LoginMixin::login called with class attribute [browser] musaka
# .
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ran 1 test in 0.000s

# OK
```