# Is this a bug in xmllint or xmlstarlet pattern matching?

Tags: regex, xml, schema, xmlstarlet, xmllint

Here is my **product.xml** file contents:

```
<ProductCode>ABC</ProductCode>
```

And here is the corresponding validating schema, **product.xsd** file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="ProductCode">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="[\P{Ll}]*"></xsd:pattern>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

I open a command line shell, and used **xmlstarlet** to validate the xml:

```
xmlstarlet val -e --xsd product.xsd product.xml
product.xml:1.31: Element 'ProductCode': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'ABC' is not accepted by the pattern '[\P{Ll}]*'.
product.xml:1.31: Element 'ProductCode': 'ABC' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
product.xml - invalid
```

Then, i tried to use **xmllint** to validate the xml:

```
└xmllint -schema product.xsd product.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductCode>ABC</ProductCode>
Element 'ProductCode': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'ABC' is not accepted by the pattern '[\P{Ll}]*'.
Element 'ProductCode': 'ABC' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
product.xml fails to validate
```

I spent a couple of hours tinkering with it and I found that I can make it work by removing the enclosing brackets:

```
<xsd:pattern value="\P{Ll}*"></xsd:pattern>
```

I can retain the enclosing brackets and make it work by using the /p inclusive pattern category and preceding it by a negation ^:

```
<xsd:pattern value="[^\p{Ll}]*"></xsd:pattern>
```

It seems, that there is a bug in the underlying implementation of **xmllint** and **xmlstarlet** and I need confirmation if indeed this is the case.

The versions I used are:

**xmllint**:

```
xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20904
compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma
```

**xmlstarlet**:

```
xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.1, linked with 20904
compiled against libxslt 1.1.28, linked with 10129
```

---

### Additional Info

Using python as coded in the snippets in [python XML schema validation snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299588/validating-with-an-xml-schema-in-python), i found that **product.xsd** does not validate **product.xml** also. It's hard to believe that python also has this bug. So therefore, I am now seeking some kind of explanation why the pattern expression in **product.xsd** is not working.

The question is: why is the enclosing bracket not able to work with the exclusive /P{Ll} ?

### More Additional Info

On the other hand, using the scala snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/ramn/725139),it is able to validate **product.xml** via **product.xsd**. So now, we can confirm that the pattern syntax in **product.xsd** is correct. Yet, xmllint, xmlstarlet and python could not validate it. What is going on here?