# xml Schema validation: How return invalid elements

Tags: python, xml

How can I return the element, line, or tag from .xml file which status was invalid.

I'm using this procedure (link below)

[Validating xml schema with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299588/validating-with-an-xml-schema-in-python)

Or you can find the code below :

validator.py

```
from lxml import etree

class Validator:

    def __init__(self, xsd_path: str):
        xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(xsd_path)
        self.xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

    def validate(self, xml_path: str) -> bool:
        xml_doc = etree.parse(xml_path)
        result = self.xmlschema.validate(xml_doc)

        return result
```

Main.py

```
import os
from validator import Validator

validator = Validator("path/to/scheme.xsd")

# The directory with XML files
XML_DIR = "path/to/directory"

for file_name in os.listdir(XML_DIR):
    print('{}: '.format(file_name), end='')

    file_path = '{}/{}'.format(XML_DIR, file_name)

    if validator.validate(file_path):
        print('Valid! :)')
    else:
        print('Not valid! :(')
```

When I run this code, I get this result,

`FILE_1.xml: Valid! :)
    FILE_2.xml: Valid! :)
    FILE_3.xml: Not valid! :(
    FILE_4.xml: Valid! :)`

My question, I don't have the information regarding which rule was broken, in other words, 
which line from FILE_3.xml broke a rule in the xsd file.
How can I return this info ?

Thank you if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `assertValid` and not `validate`. This will make that when the doc is invalid an exception will be thrown with the data you are looking  for.

See https://lxml.de/validation.html (Look for **'If you prefer getting an exception when validating, you can use the assert_ or assertValid methods**')

```
 xml_doc = etree.parse(xml_path)
 try:
     xmlschema.assertValid(xml_doc)
 except Exception as e:
     return False,str(e) 
 return True,''
```