# How to send and receive data in XML format using WebSockets in FastAPI?

Tags: python, xml, websocket, fastapi

I'm trying to communicate with a fingerprint device. Actaully it sends data through a `websocket` connection. So, I think I can communicate with the device using `webscokets`. Here I'm using FastAPI, but it only accepts `JSON` data. The problem is that I need to handle `XML` data, however, I do not know how to send and accept data in `XML` format.

Answer (score 5):

FastAPI can accept and validate other types of data as well, not only `JSON` as you stated. Have a look at the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/). Regarding `XML`, as [FastAPI is actually Starlette underneath](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#details-about-the-request-object), you can use Starlette's `Request` object directly to [read the request `body` as bytes](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body) (you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659178/17865804) helpful as well), and return a [custom `Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response) with the `XML` data (if required). You can check if the incoming request is of the required `Content-Type`, and if so, let it through; otherwise, you could raise an [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code). Below is a working example using Python requests on client side and a normal `HTTP` endpoint on server side.

#### Using `HTTP` Protocol

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, Request, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/submit")
async def submit(request: Request):
    content_type = request.headers['Content-Type']
    if content_type == 'application/xml':
        body = await request.body()
        return Response(content=body, media_type="application/xml")
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'Content type {content_type} not supported')
```

**test.py**

```
import requests

body = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><a>б</a>"""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit'
r = requests.post(url, data=body.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

In websockets, you can use `send_bytes()` and `receive_bytes()` for the communication, as described in [Starlette's documentation](https://www.starlette.io/websockets/#accepting-the-connection), allowing you to send and receive (byte encoded) `XML` data as well. If you would like to perform validation on the received `XML` data, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299588/validating-with-an-xml-schema-in-python).

#### Using `WebSocket` Protocol

Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804), which also demonstrate how to re-establish a connection on client side, if it was terminated.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def get_stream(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            contents = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            print(str(contents, 'utf-8'))
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        print("Client disconnected")   
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

**test.py**

```py
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import websockets
import asyncio

async def main():
    url = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws'
    
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        try:
            while True:
                b = bytes("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><a>б</a>", 'utf-8')
                await ws.send(b)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except ConnectionClosed:
            print("Server disconnected")
            
asyncio.run(main())
```