# Websocket getting closed immediately after connecting to FastAPI Endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, fastapi, aiohttp

I'm trying to connect a websocket aiohttp client to a fastapi websocket endpoint, but I can't send or recieve any data because it seems that the websocket gets closed immediately after connecting to the endpoint.

---

**server**

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket('/ws')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('test:app', debug=True, reload=True)
```

**client**

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    s = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    ws = await s.ws_connect('ws://localhost:8000/ws')
    while True:
        ...

asyncio.run(main())
```

---

When I try to send data from the server to the client when a connection is made

**server**

```py
@app.websocket('/ws')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    await websocket.send_text('yo')
```

**client**

```py
while True:
   print(await ws.receive())
```

I always get printed in my client's console

```
WSMessage(type=<WSMsgType.CLOSED: 257>, data=None, extra=None)
```

While in the server's debug console it says

```
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 59792) - "WebSocket /ws" [accepted]
INFO:     connection open
INFO:     connection closed
```

---

When I try to send data from the client to the server

**server**

```py
@app.websocket('/ws')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        await websocket.receive_text()
```

**client**

```py
ws = await s.ws_connect('ws://localhost:8000/ws')
await ws.send_str('client!')
```

Nothing happens, I get no message printed out in the server's console, just the debug message saying the client got accepted, connection opened and closed again.

---

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I followed [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/?h=websocket) tutorial in the fastAPI docs for a websocket and the example there with the js websocket works completely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection is closed by either end (client or server), as shown from your code snippets. You would need to have a loop in both the server and the client for being able to `await` for messages, as well as send messages, continuously (have a look [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/#await-for-messages-and-send-messages) and [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#websockets)).

Additionally, as per [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/#handling-disconnections-and-multiple-clients):

> When a WebSocket connection is closed, the `await websocket.receive_text()` will raise a `WebSocketDisconnect`
> exception, which you can then catch and handle like in this example.

Thus, on server side, you should use a `try-except` block to catch and handle `WebSocketDisconnect` exceptions, as well as `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed` exceptions, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804). Below is a working example demonstrating a client (in `aiohttp`) - server (in `FastAPI`) communication using `websockets`. Related examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415451/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804).

### Working Example

**Server**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    # await for connections
    await websocket.accept()
    
    try:
        # send "Connection established" message to client
        await websocket.send_text("Connection established!")
        
        # await for messages and send messages
        while True:
            msg = await websocket.receive_text()
            if msg.lower() == "close":
                await websocket.close()
                break
            else:
                print(f'CLIENT says - {msg}')
                await websocket.send_text(f"Your message was: {msg}")
                
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        print("Client disconnected")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

**Client**

Examples using the `websockets` library instead of `aiohttp` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415451/17865804).

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.ws_connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws') as ws:
            # await for messages and send messages
            async for msg in ws:
                if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                    print(f'SERVER says - {msg.data}')
                    text = input('Enter a message: ')
                    await ws.send_str(text)
                elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
                    break

asyncio.run(main())
```