# How can I POST data in real time using FastAPI?

Tags: python, rest, http, fastapi, real-time-data

I built a simple demo project using FastAPI. I would like to POST data to the server in real time (maybe `30fps`).

The client:

```py
while True:
    ....
    res = requests.post(URL, files={'input_data' : input_data})
    ....
```

But, I get the following error:

> (MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='~~', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url)

I think it is caused due to issuing multiple requests. I would like to perform requests in real time. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a more suitable protocol than regular http posts; instead, use websockets (supported by FastAPI/Starlette)? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @MatsLindh in the comments, you should rather use a more suitable protocol -  such as [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) - than `HTTP` for such a task. FastAPI/Starlette supports sending and receiving data on a `websocket` (see the documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) and [here](https://www.starlette.io/websockets/)).

Below is a working example of using `websockets` to send video frames from client side to server side (assuming this is your task based on your comment on `30fps` - however, the same appproach could be applied to sending other types of data). [`OpenCV`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) is used to capture the frames and [`websockets`](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) library is used to connect to the WebSocket server. More details and examples on websockets and FastAPI can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804), on which the following example is based.

### Working Example

**server.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import cv2
import numpy as np

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    # listen for connections
    await websocket.accept()
    #count = 1
    try:
        while True:
            contents = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            arr = np.frombuffer(contents, np.uint8)
            frame = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.png" % count, frame)
            #count += 1
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        cv2.destroyWindow("frame")
        print("Client disconnected")
```

**client.py**

```py
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import websockets
import asyncio
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

async def main():
    url = 'ws://localhost:8000/ws'
    
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(url):
        try:
             while True:
                success, frame = camera.read()
                if not success:
                    break
                else:
                    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
                    await websocket.send(buffer.tobytes())
                await asyncio.sleep(0.03)
        except ConnectionClosed:
            continue  # attempt reconnecting to the server (otherwise, call break)
            
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: thank you for answer! I have a question.
As in my question code, I want to get the result from the server.
is it possible to use async def websocket_endpoint?

Comment: To return a response from the server you can use, for instance , `await websocket.send_bytes(data)` or `await websocket.send_text(data)`, as documented in the links provided above. To receive the response on client side, you can use `resp = await ws.recv()`

Comment: is it possible to send data to client from server?
I wanna get output in client from server

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804) as well.