# How to pass data from thread to fastapi app in-memory eg. queue object

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi, python-multithreading

Currently I have a a program which runs a thread in python that uses asyncio to manage a websocket connection and retrieve data from this socket. I also have a fastapi app running. I would like to store the data coming from the websocket connection in a queue, and expose my API endpoints to read from this queue object. My current implementation shown below does not work and i am not sure what is the best way to pass data from a thread or asyncio event loop to a fastapi app. * note that the code below is not the actual implementation

thread.py

```
store = deque()
def main(): 
   client = WebSocketClient(store)
   thread = Thread(target=client.start)
   thread.start()

   try: 
      while True: 
         sleep(10)
   except: 
      client.stop()
      client.join()
```

client.py

```
class Client: 
   def __init__(self, store):
       self.store = store
       self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

   def start(self): 
      self.loop.run_until_complete(self.get_data())

   async def get_data(self): 
       while True: 
          data = await socket.get_data()
          self.store.append(data)
```

Fastapi app

```
from client import store #import dequeue object from different file

app = FastApi()
@app.get('/')
async def get_data(): 
   print(store). # prints empty object
   return
```

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415451/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545097/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804).