# How to validate an XML file against an XSD using the standard Python Libraries

Tags: python, xml, xsd, python-3.6, xsd-validation

I am looking to validate XML files against XSD while only using the standard Python libraries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Python standard library has no tools for XSD validation that I know of. I used the PyXB library for that in the past, but is has been abandoned by its original developer. Also the real world has taught me, that nobody really sticks to XSD-defined standards anyway, so the use of such a library is questionable at best.

Comment: It's not possible with just the standard library. Old similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/299588/407651

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen anything but wanted to double check

Comment: Check it out here: https://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml